# Programmatically delete a row from tableView from its customCell class with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**GOAL**

*To delete a row from the TableView called from `customTableViewCell`*

I have a `tableView` in my `CustomTableViewController` which **deque**'s a `customTableViewCell`.

In that `customTableViewCell` class i have a `UIButton` Action which needs to change its buttonTitle when pressed, accordingly and delete the row itself if required.For this i am passing the indexPath of that cell to a globalVariable in that `customTableViewCell` class, which i use to delete my row accessing through the instance of `CustomTableViewController`.

**CODE**

Code for `retrieving` the database from firebase and `struct` is unnecessary ,just included for reference.

`CustomTableViewController` which has embed `tableView` in it:-

```
class FriendsListController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource,addingFriendDelegate{

  var profileFeed = [profileStruct]() //profileFeed is the an array of type struct, in which i am storing my retrieved database value's
   var customCellHandler = FriendsTableViewCell() 
  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    listTableView.delegate = self
    listTableView.dataSource = self
     customCellHandler.delegate = self
    if friendListTable == true && profileFeed.isEmpty == true{

        FIRControllerHandle.retrievingForTheFriendListTableView { (userName, lctn, ID) in

            let temp = profileStruct.init(userName: userName, location: lctn, UID: ID)
            self.profileFeed.insert(temp, atIndex: 0)
            self.listTableView.reloadData()
            self.presentViews()

        }

    }else if friendListTable == false && profileFeed.isEmpty == true{

        print(profileFeed)
        print(profileFeed.isEmpty)

        FIRControllerHandle.retrievingForThePendingFriendRequests({ (userName, location, userId) in

            if self.profileFeed.isEmpty == true{

            let temp = profileStruct.init(userName: userName, location: location, UID: userId)
            self.profileFeed.insert(temp, atIndex: 0)
            self.listTableView.reloadData()
            self.presentViews()
            }
        })
      }
    }

    //Code for storing the data in a struct  is just for reference , trivial w.r.t context of my question

   }


   //addindFriendDelegate methods
  func deleteRowAtTheIndex(index: NSIndexPath){

        listTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([index], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

     }


//TableView delegate Functions.

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return profileFeed.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = listTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendsCell") as! FriendsTableViewCell

    cell.userNameLabel.text = profileFeed[indexPath.row].profileName
    cell.userUID = profileFeed[indexPath.row].profileUserId
    cell.userName = profileFeed[indexPath.row].profileName
    cell.userLocationLabel.text = profileFeed[indexPath.row].profileLocation
    cell.currentUserName = currentuserName_initial
    cell.friendsListBool = friendListTable
    cell.cellIndexPath = indexPath   //Sending the indexPath of that row


    return cell

  }
}
```

---

`customTableViewCell`  class which responds to buttons action:-

```
protocol addingFriendDelegate {
func deleteRowAtTheIndex(index: NSIndexPath)
    }

class FriendsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var userName : String!
var userLocation : String!
var userUID : String!
var FIRControllerHandle : FIRController = FIRController() //I am using firebase as my backend and `FIRController` class handles all the firebase functions.
var delegate: addingFriendDelegate!
var friendsListBool : Bool = true // I am managing two tableViews datasource in one tableView , and `friendsListBool` tells me which node to retrieve from my database.
var currentUserName : String!
var cellIndexPath : NSIndexPath!
var listTableViewController : FriendsListController = FriendsListController() // Instance of viewController in which my tableView is embed


 @IBAction func addFriendsBtnAction(sender: CustomButton) {

    if friendsListBool{
    FIRControllerHandle.sendFriendRequest(userUID, completionBlock: {

           self.addFriendsBtn.setTitle("Sent", forState: .Normal) //Setting the title

           print(self.cellIndexPath.row) //Printing Fine
           self.listTableViewController.listTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([self.cellIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)


    })

    } else if !friendsListBool {

        FIRControllerHandle.accepFriendRequest(currentUserName, friendID: userUID, friendName : userName ,completionBlock: {

            self.addFriendsBtn.setTitle("Friends", forState: .Normal)



           })
       }
   }
}
```

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED**

```
self.listTableViewController.listTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([self.cellIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

called in `@IBAction func addFriendsBtnAction(sender: CustomButton)` where `listTableViewController` is Instance of viewController in which my tableView is embed, and `cellIndexPath` indexPath of the row i want to delete

**LINE OF ERROR**

```
self.listTableViewController.listTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([self.cellIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

*Error*:- *fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

*(lldb)*

PS:- I am not particularly inclined towards `protocol-delegate` method for this.I am looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never** initialize a view controller with the default initializer like `FriendsListController()`.
It will create a brand new instance which is not the instance you expect in the view hierarchy.

An suitable alternative to protocol / delegate is a completion closure.

According to your latest code change the following:

- Delete

  ```
  var customCellHandler = FriendsTableViewCell()
  var delegate: addingFriendDelegate!
  ```
- Insert in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

  ```
  cell.delegate = self
  ```
- Insert in `deleteRowAtTheIndex`

  ```
  profileFeed.removeAtIndex(index.row)
  ```

Comment: But will `protocol / delegate` be better than `completion closure.`? Also code line which i am using to delete the row , would it work fine..? Thanks for your input btw :)

Comment: In my personal opinion a closure is much better (and easier) than protocol / delegate. Practically you should avoid to *bite the hand that feeds you* that means don't put the code to delete an object in the object itself. That's the business of the controller not the view.

Comment: Same issue: `FriendsTableViewCell()` is **not** the (single) cell you expect. A table view can have dozens of (different) table view cells. Please try to understand how a table view works.

Comment: PS: And you will run into the next fatal problem if you delete the item only in the (table) view and not in the model (data source), too.

Comment: The easiest way using your code is to remove the lines `var customCellHandler = FriendsTableViewCell()` and `customCellHandler.delegate = self` and to insert  `cell.delegate = self` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Further insert `profileFeed.removeAtIndex(index.row) ` in the delegate method `deleteRowAtTheIndex`